# Wordpress: url to all posts for home.php

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm develop a theme for **WordPress** and I have created **index.php** for the original loop, and **home.php** for 4 latest posts, now I need to put a link for show all posts, how to I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of a link to show all posts, I would use WordPress's have_posts() function inside a while loop (first check to see if there are posts to display, if there are do so, if not exit loop and display other content). You could potentially look at WP's documentation for the function and maybe even glance at file used for the default page template (page.php).

In order to display only the latest 4 posts, you could simply add a counter variable and end each while loop iteration with an if statement checking to see if count == 4.

Also, just so you are aware, home.php sometimes takes precedence over index.php so either nest home.php inside an internal directory or call your '4 latest posts' page 'posts.php' or something similar.

Wordpress documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/have_posts

Comment: it's not my answer

Answer (score 0):

```
To get latest post with url:
<?php
        $args = array( 'numberposts' => '1', 'category' => CAT_ID );
        $recent_posts = wp_get_recent_posts( $args );
        foreach( $recent_posts as $recent ){
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink($recent["ID"]) . '">Latest Post</a>';`enter code here`
        }
    ?>
Hope this helps .
```